# imageMagick installation problems

Tags: imagemagick, centos

I have installed imageMagick but i get a warning loaded PHP Startup. How can i solve this?

```
[root@vps06 /]# identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.1-10 2013-07-18 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms png ps tiff x zli

[root@vps06 /]# php -m | grep imagick
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - libfftw3.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the [imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) module for PHP. The easiest way would be with the [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/) command.

```sh
sudo pecl install imagick
```

You can also manually install this package if you need more control of your local build

```sh
curl -O http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
tar zxvf imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz && cd imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
phpize
./configure # Add custom build options here
make
sudo make install
```